# How to change screen resolution in Windows 10 version 20h2

Tags: windows-10, boot, resolution

Specifications:
Processor: Intel Pentium G2020.
Ram: 4 gb.
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro Version 20h2.
I was just trying to make my tv as my pc monitor,and I increased the screen resolution and it showed "NO SIGNAL".
Then I connected it to the monitor I used before but the problem persists.
The solutions which I have already tried:

1. Restarting.
2. Trying to boot to boot options menu from where I can boot to safe mode.But I can't because version 20h2 doesn't support f8 key.Also I don't have operating system disk as it is in the form of iso which is in my pc.
3. Trying to force windows to crash by powercut out.
4. Trying some key combinations with keyboard so that I can change the resolution in the background.
5. Resetting BIOS.
   Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: How did you increase the screen resolution? Can you undo it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once Windows has fully loaded:

1. Press enter then type your PIN or password if you have one then wait a minute or 2 for the desktop to load.
2. Move the mouse to the top right then right-click for the desktop context menu then press <kbd>D</kbd> for display settings.
3. Wait a few seconds then <kbd>TAB</kbd> 4 times and then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, <kbd>END</kbd>, <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

This should set the screen resolution to the lowest. It's possible that the number of times you press tab might be more or less.

If you have sound you can open Narrator when at the desktop by pressing <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `narrator` then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. This will help ensure you are doing the right things.

Comment: Thank you it worked for me.The resolution was set to 800x600.I also watched a video same as you which showed some key combination in the keyboard but it didn't work.Thanks once again you save my pc.